# paraphrasing a participle phrase

Tags: grammar

▪️ The old woman walked slowly to the elevator, **assisted by the porter**.

Q: Can I paraphrase the bold part this way?

(1) The old woman walked slowly to the elevator, the porter assisting her.

(2) The old woman walked slowly to the elevator, with the porter assisting her.

Comment: By me(The old woman walked slowly to the elevator. She was assisted by the porter.)

Comment: Yes, you can paraphrase them like that.

Comment: They do have slightly different meanings. Present participle is more likely to indicate an ongoing process, and past, something that happened before or at the start. But it's also common to select which to use on the basis of which is shorter and simpler, as there is not a huge difference in meaning. (You don't say why you want to paraphrase it or what the precise meaning is, so it's impossible to give a better recommendation.)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase in bold is correct, 1) is incorrect, 2) is incorrect.

In 1), the phrase "the porter assisting her" is what is known as a "dangling clause".  It is disconnected from the rest of the sentence and should be connected, as it is in 2).

Although it is technically incorrect, you will sometimes see it in both spoken and written English.  But you should avoid dangling clauses, because they can sometimes sound wrong, seem unprofessional, or carry unintended meaning.

In 2), if you remove the comma between "elevator" and "with", it will be correct.